# Returning an array of functions: creating closures

Tags: javascript, function, closures

Given this function call:

```
var funcs = obj.getClosures([2, 4, 6, 8], function(x) {
    return x*x;
});
```

I have the following function:

```
getClosures : function(arr, fn) {
    var funcs = [];
    var array = arr;
    var i = 0;
    var l = array.length;

    (function(i, array) {

        for (; i < l; i++) {
            funcs[i] = function(i, array) {
                return fn(array[i]);
            };
        }

    }(i, array));

    return funcs; 

},
```

I'd like to be able to loop through the returned array and get the square root values of each item in the array exactly like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   funcs[i]();
}
```

results each time through loop : 4, 16, 36, 64

Shouldn't my funcs array have a function reference in each index that can be readily invoked with the relevant argument values? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I'm suprprised it does something at all. It should throw errors because you don't pass any arguments to the function call ( `funcs[i]()` ).

Comment: JavaScript will not produce errors if more or less arguments are supplied. Instead it will ignore extra ones or set missing ones to "undefined"

Comment: @mishik: If your comment was in response to mine, even though you are correct, `array[i]` will throw an error if `array` is `undefined` (which would be the case if no arguments are passed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There multiple "issues":

The IIFE `(function(i, array) { ...  }(i, array));` has no benefit at all here. If you remove it the code will have the exact same behavior. If you want to capture the current value of `i` and `array`, you would have to move it *inside* the `for` loop.

Your function definition is incorrect.

```
funcs[i] = function(i, array) {
    return fn(array[i]);
};
```

Inside the function, `array[i]` will refer to the *arguments* you pass to the function. If you don't pass any, they will be `undefined` and the code will throw an error. That is, with that definition, you would have to execute the functions like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   funcs[i](i, array);
}
```

which kind of defeats the purpose of generating the functions in the first place.

If you want to create a closure which has access to `i` and `array` of the scope where the function was defined in, don't define parameters with the same name.

Possible solution:

```
for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        funcs[i] = function() {
            return fn(array[i]);
        };
    }(i));
}
```

Or simpler, if your code runs in environments which support [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
getClosures: function(arr, fn) {
    return arr.map(function(v) {
        return function() {
            fn(v);
        };
    });
},
```

Related questions:

- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/218196)

Comment: +1; alternatively, move `funcs[i] =` inside the IIFE. This lets you assign more than one handler per IIFE, and is a little more idiomatic IMO.

Comment: @Jan: I was actually wondering which of the ways to choose. I changed it now, since I think it's a bit closer to the original code and might be easier to understand then. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Felix! This was an exercise for me in learning closures, and your points are extremely helpful! The missteps of having the IIFE outside the loop and thinking I had to nest the arguments in each function are now clearer to me. This is getting easier :-)

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var obj = {
getClosures : function(arr, fn) {
     var funcs = [];
    var array = arr;
    var i = 0;
    var l = array.length;

    (function(i, array) {

        for (; i < l; i++) {
            funcs[i] = function(i, array) {
                return fn(array[i]);
            }.bind(this,i,array);
        }

    }(i, array));

    return funcs; 

}
}

var funcs = obj.getClosures([2, 4, 6, 8], function(x) {
    return x*x;
});

for (var i = 0; i < funcs.length; i++) {
   console.log(funcs[i]());
}
```

Outputs:

```
4
16
36
64
```

It works since javascript 1.8.5 (firefox 4). I have no idea for other browsers but there is implementation for older versions (should work on older browsers as well)